# detect when each task is complete

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I want to update a progressbar as each task is completed below.

The method var continuation2 = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(..... doesnt work.

What is the correct way to do this?

**C# Code**

```
  private void radButtonInsertManyErrors_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                radProgressBarStatus.Maximum = int.Parse(radTextBoxNumberofErrorsInsert.Text);
                radProgressBarStatus.Value1 = 0;


                Task<int>[] tasks = new Task<int>[int.Parse(radTextBoxNumberofErrorsInsert.Text)];

                for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(radTextBoxNumberofErrorsInsert.Text); i++)
                {
                    int x = i;
                    tasks[i] = new Task<int>(() =>
                    {

                        //insert the error into table FA_Errors
                        Accessor.Insert_FAErrors(BLLErrorCodes.BLL_Error_Codes.Error_Log_Event_Login.ToString(),
                                                     (int)BLLErrorCodes.BLL_Error_Codes.Error_Log_Event_Login,
                                                     "Some Error", "",
                                                 MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Namespace.ToString(),
                                                 MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString(),
                                                 BLLErrorCategory.BLL_Error_Category.WEB_APP.ToString(),
                                                "pc source", "damo",
                                                 sConn.ToString());
                        return 1;


                    });
                }

                var continuation = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
                            tasks,
                            (antecedents) =>
                            {
                                RadMessageBox.Show("Finished inserting errors ");
                            });


                var continuation2 = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(
                tasks,
                (antecedents) =>
                {
                        radProgressBarStatus.Value1++;

                });


                for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(radTextBoxNumberofErrorsInsert.Text); i++)
                    tasks[i].Start();
                // Use next line if you want to block the main thread until all the tasks are complete
                //continuation.Wait();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());

            }   

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
public static void TaskProgress(IEnumerable<Task> tasks, Action<int> callback)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var task in tasks)
        task.ContinueWith(t => callback(Interlocked.Increment(ref count)));
}
```

It will call the callback each time a task completes with the number of currently completed tasks.  Note that the callbacks are not synchronized, so it can be called while the previous callback is still running.

Comment: how do i call that method?

Comment: @user1438082 `TaskProgress(tasks, count => Invoke(new MethodInvoker(()=>radProgressBarStatus.Value1 = count)));`

Comment: i get the error "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate, params object[])' has some invalid arguments" after inserting this line of code

Answer (score 2):

Set up a continuation with each of the tasks. Keep a (thread-safe) counter on how many completed and update the UI on completion of each task.

Actually, `Task.WhenAll` does keep such a counter under the hood. It is just not accessible.

Comment: so if i have 1000 tasks - then i have to create 1000 continuations?

Comment: @user1438082 Yes.  That needs to be done.  Having some function do it for you would only ever hide it, not prevent it from happening.

Comment: Continuations are relatively cheap. Certainly cheaper than what the task does so the cost of the task's body masks the cost of the continuation.